# Error when creating a user {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to create an Azure Active Directory User using ADAL and I get this error:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Property  value is required but is empty or missing."},"values":null}}
```

Stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.Services.Client.SaveResult.HandleResponse()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseSaveResult.EndRequest()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.EndSaveChanges(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.<SaveChangesAsync>d__74.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at CapatechSaasApp.Areas.GlobalAdmin.UsuarioController.<Create>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Proyectos\xx\xx\Areas\GlobalAdmin\Controllers\UsuarioController.cs:line 143
```

My code is mainly a copy paste from this sample:

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GraphAPI-DotNet/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/Views/Users/Create.cshtml

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GraphAPI-DotNet/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/Controllers/UsersController.cs

I tried setting the language by code:

```
user.PreferredLanguage= "en"
```

but that didnt make any difference, the error doesn't say which property must be set.

Comment: shame on the -1, post a constructive criticism

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several tries I noticed I was missing the property AccountEnabled to be set, weird that the message is not clear enough, it should say which property value is missing

Comment: Good to see you got this resolved. I'll forward this feedback to the team. :)

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Just another data point: same behaviour here. Other properties reported as missing in the odata error message. AccountEnabled not.

Comment: This is still not fixed as of this comment 6/15. I found this myself.